# how to call axes and add it in a new figure in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to combine the two figures in t1.py and t2.py. l import the two axis named ax1 int1.py and ax2 in t2.py in the new file t.py. now I set a figure in t.py, l want to add the imported two axes as subplots in the new figure, how can l do it?
I have tried one way to do it, but is not well enough:

this is t1.py file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from t import ax01 as ax1
ax1.plot([2,4,5,6,9])
```

this is t2.py file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from t import ax02 as ax1
ax1.plot([.2,.4,.5,.6,0.9])
```

this is t.py file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1,(ax01,ax02)=plt.subplots(1,2);
execfile('t1.py')
execfile('t2.py')
plt.show()
```

however, this will call the execfile function.

Comment: Can you modify the code in `t1.py` and `t2.py`? If so, it is much easier to allow the user to create and pass axes to the plotting functions in `t1.py` and `t2.py` instead of having `t1` and `t2` create axes attached to different figures and then having to mend the problem after-the-fact.

Comment: I have found how you can add `ax1` to a figure in another script: `from t1 import ax1; f=plt.figure(); ax1.figure=f; f.add_axes(ax1)` but I cannot find how to add the second axes.